# Why credentials used by an Azure Function running locally don't work even if the same credentials work in the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

An Azure Function locally using Visual Studio is not authorized to read a document from Cosmos using my credentials. However, I'm able to read and write documents using the Azure Portal. Now if I add the role to my principal, the function is allowed to run locally successfully. Why?

> Forbidden (403); Reason: (Request blocked by Auth
> cosmos-pocif-dev-wus2-1 : Request is blocked because principal
> [4eaac860-308b-4a42-b70e-f727181e69d8] does not have required RBAC
> permissions to perform action
> [Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata] on resource.

Comment: I might think your app is not running under your credentials when deployed into Azure. Did you setup managed identity and gave access to cosmos for the app identity?

Comment: Nothing deployed, it is running locally

Comment: Interesting, I have found similar problems when running VS with my Microsoft account (hotmail, msn) and I have multiple tenants (different AAD accounts). In my case my account is used in multiple tenants.

Answer (score 0):

I found the recent reported issue in MS Q&A Azure Cosmos DB Tagged Forum with the same error while reading-from and writing the data to the Cosmos Database - #[802755](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/802755/role-required-to-read-write-data-from-cosmos-db-(s))

but your source is Azure Functions and here the user's source is ADF.

> ErrorMessage: Request blocked by AuthcosmosDB: Request is because principal [xyzx-abcd-xxx] does not have required RBAC permissions to perform action.

An MSFT User @*PradeepCheekatla-MSFT* provided the solution that because of insufficient RBAC permissions on `[Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata]` and requires the Service principal level access and has given the process of resolving the issue is that service principal gets assigned with the Cosmos DB Data Roles such as Reader and Contributor.